# Can TabWidget in TabHost be not selected when TabActivity starts first time?

Tags: android

I have a class which extends TabActivity in which I have 3 TabWidgets. When my activity starts for the first time my first Tab is already selected but I want to not select any of the TabWidget till the user selects any Tab. Can we do it in Android, it is very necessary to complete that task.

Please look into this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If nothing is selected, what do you whant to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make index one more by the value.

Means if you have four tabs in your activity make it five or if you have 2 tabs make it three. This TabIndex selects that number of index. So it will see to select number 5 or 3 as an index, so when your activity starts no tab will be selected.

Enjoy.  !!!

Comment: its not working this anyhelp. I am using setCurrentTab(5) , i only have three tabs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the selected tab to -1?

Comment: Yes tried but same thing is happening. Nothing is changed first Tab is selected.